# Can I sync or transfer save games and settings from one platform to another?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I would like to know if the same Minecraft account used on a computer can be used on a different platform like the Xbox 360? I am not asking about playing on each simultaneously as each platform has been purchased - I am asking if you can cross play on multiple platforms with the same account. Basically I would like to know if all the saved stuff and settings from one platform will carry over to another.

Comment: So you want to play on the same map on both console and pc? Or you want to play cooperatively on both at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

A PC/Max/Linux Minecraft account cannot be used on an XBOX, and vice versa. Furthermore, world save files are not tied to your account, they're saved on your computer, so will not transfer automatically - even between two PCs.

There do appear to be some [tools](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zmntllg8tab985u/oPryzeLP_setup.exe.) and [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FA8-OO6E80) that allow you to transfer the world from PC to XBOX, but keep in mind:

- These are not supported by Mojang or 4J Studios
- The XBOX version doesn't support all PC features; you will lose any newer blocks/items
- The conversion is said to take ~10 minutes, and is quite involved
- The PC world is larger than XBOX ones, so you'll lose anything that it cannot fit

Overall I would not recommend it if you're just wanting to play the same world on both devices. The tools I've found are more for one-time conversions and require quite a lot of work for each transfer.