# Is it possible to port ps4 or xb1 minecraft saves to pc minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I'm mostly wondering if there any way to port or convert minecraft ps4 saves into a format that is compatible with pc minecraft. I only own a ps4 and a pc, but I'm still curious if it's possible to do the same for xbox. Also, are there any legal reasons not to convert files from one platform to another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I sync or transfer save games and settings from one platform to another?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198507/can-i-sync-or-transfer-save-games-and-settings-from-one-platform-to-another)

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct duplicate of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198507/can-i-sync-or-transfer-save-games-and-settings-from-one-platform-to-another) Arqade question, the [answer to that question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/198566/91583) is of relevance to yours.

Please keep in mind the following items:

- These are not supported by Mojang or 4J Studios
- The XBOX version doesn't support all PC features; you will lose any newer blocks/items
- The conversion is said to take ~10 minutes, and is quite involved
- The PC world is larger than XBOX ones, so you'll lose anything that it cannot fit

*This list is copied verbatim from the answer linked, and credit goes to the SE user @colorfusion.*